# Automorphisms of a neighborhood of a negative curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $X$ e a smooth complex surface and let $C\subset X$ be a smooth rational curve with negative self intersection.

Is there any known description of the automorphisms of a infinitesimal neighborhood of $C$ in $X$? Note that it is the same as a infinitesimal neighborhood of the zero section of the normal bundle of $C$, by Grauert's theorem.

Comment: Please define "germ of a manifold $(X,C)$".  If $X$ is birational to an Abelian surface $Y$, for example, then every automorphism of any dense Zariski open subset of $X$ arises from a unique biregular automorphism of $Y$.  So there is no hope of classifying automorphisms only from the information of $C$ and the degree of the normal bundle of $C$ in $X$.  However, if you intend "germ" to mean the formal completion of $X$ along $C$, that is quite different.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I edited te question. I hope it is clearer.